# Extension Library UserBean cache

Tags: caching, xpages, acl

I'm working with the Extension Library Managed Bean "UserBean".  I'm trying a simple proof to test the ACL property of a panel with the userBean.  Then I have three panels on the page with text in them.  Here is one of the panels.

to display my current roles.

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{javascript:return userBean.accessRoles.toString();}"></xp:text>



   <xp:panel id="panelMarketing" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
            <xp:this.loaded><![CDATA[${javascript:var roles = userBean.accessRoles.toString();
return roles.contains("[MARKETING]");}]]></xp:this.loaded>
        </xp:acl>
    </xp:this.acl>
    <xp:label value="I'm in Marketing" id="label2"></xp:label>
</xp:panel>
```

I load the page while I have the 3 Roles assigned to me.  Panel displays.  Remove the role, all panels still display and the text field that returns the user roles still shows the old role that was assigned to me in the ACL.  Seams like UserBean is not reading the ACL again.

Then I try CTRL F5, still nothing.  I then open another browser, log into the app and still the same roles.  Close the browsers, log back in and no change.

Is there a flush time or a way to force the userBean to update the users ACL roles?

The next day I log back in and the UserBean reflects my changes.  I make another change and the UserBean does not reflect the change.

Comment: I guess your userBean is defined with application scope. Change that to session scope then it gets new instantiated accessing from another browser.

Comment: The 'another browser' part in Knut's comment is important here: a session scoped bean is linked to the browser session, not a 9logged in) user session. A full restart of the browser will also do the trick.

Comment: I did close my browser and ended my session.  I even tried using another computer... that was yesterday.  Today, I see the bean has cleared and its showing the correct Roles.  Made a change in the ACL, and the UserBean is not updated.  Can I force the UserBean using the faces-config? will that create two instances?  Is there a config setting somewhere for the Extension Library to tell it to load the UserBean in a specific scope?

Answer (score 0):

For the acl add an aclEntry and do not code the loaded property, like this ...

```
<xp:panel id="panelMarketing" style="border:1px solid red;">
    <xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
            <xp:this.entries>
                <xp:aclEntry right="READER" type="ROLE">
                    <xp:this.name><![CDATA[[MARKETING]]]></xp:this.name>
                </xp:aclEntry>
            </xp:this.entries>
        </xp:acl>
    </xp:this.acl>
    <xp:label value="I'm in Marketing" id="label8"></xp:label>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I can use this in the meantime, but would like to trust the userBean throughout the application.  The answer I need is related to the userBean object loaded with the Extension Library accessed using the userBean object in code.  userBean seems to update itself against the ACL the next day usually.

Comment: I did more testing and it appears that the acl settings are cached as well.  The good news is the acl is refreshed when the user starts a new session unlike the userBean which doesn't refresh for a day.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the Extension Library book (see page 464) and the source code for the userBean implementation it appears that userBeans are cached in application scope with a default cache size set to 100 (because you can use userBean to access details about other users than just the current user).

The userBean works with the user being authenticated in the session. So the userBean is basically a shortcut for peopleBean.getPerson() in Java.

The peopleBean class has a refreshPerson(id) method and a clearcache(id) method. Try using one of these to force the peopleBean/userBean to refresh by doing either `peopleBean.refreshPerson(@UserName())` or `peopleBean.clearcache(@UserName())`.

Comment: No change.  I called these methods without error in beforePageLoad and afterPageLoad, then I tried calling one and then the other clearcache first then refreshPerson.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 years ago but I had the same problem and decided to investigate further.

It turns out there are several bugs in the underlying clearCache(String id) method which is supposed to clear a single cache entry (e.g. a person). Consequently had no effect when used on a application, session or request scope cache. (it did work for a global cache though so I suspect that was the only one they tested).

I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/pull/78) to the Extension Library to fix the clearCache(string id) method so hopefully it gets accepted for the next release!

The clearCache() method which clears all entries *does* work so you could always try

```
peopleBean.clearCache();
```

and that should work (it does for me) however it clears every persons entry which shouldn't be a big problem, they will just load again I guess.